# I can't select "Armature" when adding a Track To constraint

Tags: rigging

So, after adding a track to constraint to the bone that will follow the eye bone, I try to select "Armature" but when I click it, it wont add it to the "Target:" field.  Furthermore, I noticed that it says "Add Object Contraint".  It should say "Add Bone Constraint".  Please refer to the photo below.  I want to make the "Armature" option appear in the field after I click it and I want to make sure that above, it says "Add Bone Constraint".  Can someone help me?  Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've clicked on the *Object Constraints* tab, where you could give a constraint to the whole armature, it's not what you want, what you want is the *Bone Constraints*. To have access to this tab you need to switch to *Pose* mode, select your bone, click on the right tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  It worked!  Thank you!